# C# XML b64 text to PDF

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, base64, itext

I'm looking for some help on doing this. 
Basically, I have a b64 "string" in a XML file which "translates" into a PDF file(text+images) when decoded. I need a way to be able to do that, hope you can help me.

Best regards,
Bruno Vieira

Comment: If you decode the base64 string, what do you get? An image? Then where is the text? Text? Then where are the images? iText has a Base64 decoder class, and iText can create PDFs from images and text, but your question is incomplete. It's as if you haven't looked inside the Base64 string yourself.

Comment: Someone has encoded this data. Could you show us that code?

Comment: Step 1: Decode the Base64 text to binary, either an array or a file.  Step 2: Write (or rename) the binary to a file "MyFile.pdf".  Assuming everything worked, you should have a working PDF file on your disc.

Comment: I already saw the Base64 decoded into a document. It is definitely well encoded. Unfortunately, i can't provide all the base64 information since it is confidential, but it really is well encoded. I just need a way to decode it into a string, so it can then be put into a final pdf file. Can someone get me a good example on this?

Comment: Dear Bruno, your question "Can someone get me a good example on this?" is kind of insulting because I already gave you the answer; but you didn't bother to look at it. I repeat: iText has a Base64 decoder class, and you don't need a code sample, you need a simple method named `Decode`. It is present in iText 5 (http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/Base64.html#decode-java.lang.String-) as well as in iText 7 (http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/io/codec/Base64.html#decode-java.lang.String-). It accepts a string and returns a byte array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't make myself clear, when i was referring to an "example" i was talking about a successfull PDF file creation that involved a text+image(s) body in it. I understood what you meant before on the decoding part, thank you.